# Why is my object not assigned to layer?

Tags: objects, layers

I disabled the view of all layers, but a certain object is still visible. Why? How can i hide this object or how can i assign it to a layer?

Thx
[image]

Comment: It could be assigned to more than one layer, in the 3D_view press M and select the layer, hiding the parent will not effect the children (not in  real life : )

Comment: Ok what i mean are the different scene layers, not the layer in the 3D view. In the 3D view everything is on layer 1.

Comment: the same for scene layers : an object can be on multiple scene  layers

Comment: You can toggle visibility of any objects by H / Alt+H. This won't affect on which layer it was assigned, but rather than only visibility.

Comment: @MrZak Thanks, selecting the objects and pressing H made them hide.

Comment: @Internet It may be done within the Properties window which is opened on your screenshot. Just hover mouse over object you'd like to hide and press Eye button (or unpress). Same with possibility to edit mesh.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you aren't seeing all your objects in the outliner.

Your object is parented to another object.
You'll noticed that when the object in question is selected, one of the inverted triangle icons next to the parent object is highlighted rather then another entry.

Click the + next to the parent object to expand the view and show that object's child objects:

[image]